# html5 drag and drop with three.js trackball control

Tags: html, three.js

Currently I have a 3D model that can be rotated/translated/zoom in-out using TrackballControls in THREE.js on the body of my html.

At the same time, I need a drag and drop interface on top of the model layer. I have implemented using this sample: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp

The issue is that I cannot drag and drop the image because the mouse drag detected will be used to control the model by TrackballControls.

I understand that another possibility is to render my image in webGL directly instead of using html, like discussed here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1959. I can detect mouse position and do my processing from that onwards. However this is not preferable as I might have a lot of icons to drag and drop.

Hence, is there possible way to implement html5 drag and drop on top of THREE.js TrackballControls? I was thinking something along using z-index for the div. But when we are adding the renderer like below there is no way to specify.

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: false } );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

container = document.createElement( 'div' );
document.body.appendChild( container );
container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Maybe you can listen on _dragging_ events directly on the `canvas` element and `event.preventDefault()` it. You may have to specify an upper element in `TrackballControls`, though

Comment: @vincent thanks for your input, what do you mean by upper element?

Comment: I mean the html parent of the canvas